# How to change text after delay and loop it back?

Tags: jquery, css, loops, delay

I am trying this "Text in Transparent Box" using CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.background
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url(image.jpg) repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div.transbox
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
div.transbox p
{
  text-align:center;
  margin: 4px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div class="background" style="display:inline-block">
<div class="transbox" style="display:inline-block">
<p>This is my first position</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I automatically change position of transparent box and text after 5secs delay and again and then loop it allover again?
Check this screenshot image:

```
Image 1 for position1 :http://i57.tinypic.com/x3detu.jpg

Image 2 for position 2:http://i60.tinypic.com/ipnw5v.png

Image 3 for position 3:http://i58.tinypic.com/2lnff3t.png

Loop this back to Position1
```

## **EDIT**

Code added as you advised, but it doesn't work::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
div.background
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url(banner.jpg) no-repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div.transbox
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
div.transbox p
{
  text-align:center;
  margin: 4px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script>
    (function($) {
        var transbox = $('div.transbox');

        (function runIt() {
            transbox
            .delay(1500).animate({"top": "70px"}, 1000)
            .delay(500).animate({"top": "160px"}, 1000)
            .delay(500).animate({"top": ""}, 200, function () {runIt();});
        }());
    }());
</script>


<div class="background" style="display:inline-block">
<div class="transbox" style="display:inline-block">
<p>This is my first position</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery makes this pretty easy:

```
var transbox = $('div.transbox');

(function runIt() {
    transbox
    .delay(1500).animate({"top": "70px"}, 1000)
    .delay(500).animate({"top": "160px"}, 1000)
    .delay(500).animate({"top": ""}, 200, function () {runIt();});
}());
```

Note that for this to work, you'll also need to add a `position: relative` to your css for `div.transbox`

http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/Gj6tN/

If you don't want the animation effect, you can set the easings to 0 (the easings are the 1000, 1000, and 200 that define how long the animation should take). Or you could change `.animate()` to `.css()` but that doesn't take a callback so you'd have to chain another call.

## EDIT

You can pass whatever css rules you want to the `.animate()` method. I've shown an example of moving horizontally as well as vertically. And I've added the changing text.

http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/YuJ8K/

## EDIT 2

You need jQuery. From your question's tags, I assumed you were already using it, but maybe you aren't. The easiest way to include jQuery is to use the version hosted at google.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, you need to wrap the javascript code in a script tag and in some sort of event that will fire after page ready. Any javascript (jQuery or otherwise) that you add into the

`$("document").ready(function() { //code here });`

enclosure will get executed when the page is ready.

```
<body>
    <script>
    $("document").ready(function() {
        var transbox = $('div.transbox');

        (function runIt() {
            transbox
            .delay(1500).animate({"top": "70px"}, 1000)
            .delay(500).animate({"top": "160px"}, 1000)
            .delay(500).animate({"top": ""}, 200, function () {runIt();});
        }());
    });
    </script>

    ....rest of html....
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Pabo, your code is nice, but the text does not change, I want the text also to change.
I want the postion to change, as well the containing text.
And what if the position has to be changed horizontally as well as vertically?

Comment: Thanks a ton Pabo, your code is wow..!!
Sorry for being a noob, I am new here... where do I put the javascript?? I included it in head, but it didnt work, didnt work if I put the javascript in body too..
Sorry for the trouble and thanks a ton..!!

Comment: Please check out my Edit above, I have posted the whole code for your perusal, it does not work.
Inspect element in Chrome shows this error:: 
Uncaught Typeerror: undefined is not a function

Comment: Whoops, I gave you the wrong snippet. I've updated it above. Specifically, it now correctly uses     $("document").ready(function() { });

And don't forget to add position:relative to your css like my original note mentioned.

Comment: Hey Pabo, thanks a ton, it works like charm..!! :)

Just wanted to ask, what if we dont want to move transbox, but render transbox again according to the length of text which moved. Like at position one, text is of 1 word, transbox is of 1 word length, at position 2, text changes to 3words and transbox is new one according to the text length , at position 3, text moves again and now is of 6 words and transbox changes accordingly.
Is that possible? :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking. Do you have some images to mock up what it should look like?

Comment: Here I upload a screenshot (3 pics):
http://s22.postimg.org/ud3edhw5d/trans.png

As you can see, I changed the transparent box width and height as per the text. Now in your code, we are animating the transparent box, so its size cannot be changed. Hope you got it from image

Comment: As I said, "You can pass whatever css rules you want to the .animate() method." w3schools is a good reference for these. See the width rule here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp.